# QXmlSchemaValidator segfaults on XSD union

Tags: c++, qt, xsd

For clarity, the following affects Qt4.7. I don't know if Qt5 is affected.

When validating XML using [QXmlSchemaValidator](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qxmlschemavalidator.html) I find that Qt segfaults on [XSD unions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_union.asp)

Example:

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="dayOfWeek">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:integer dayAsString"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="dayAsString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Monday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Friday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Saturday"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Sunday"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This construct validated well in other applications. I used Notepad++ with the XML Tools plugin for instance.

But the same XSD used with QXmlSchemaValidator causes my application to crash.

Which leaves me with the question:

Can a union of an attribute like this be achieved in XSD in some other way?

Comment: If it also affects more recent Qt versions, I'd file a Qt big report, no matter the validity, the validator should never crash.

Comment: Is it the union that is causing it to crash?   Why not just add the values 1-7 as strings to the dayAsString.

Comment: Qt support xml 1.0 only(?) Try validate schema too: QXmlSchema schema; schema.load(schemaFile.readAll()); if (!schema.isValid()) { ...

Comment: @Deep Yup, the code already does exactly that and it passes that check.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I think a bug report (QTBUG-77620) was filed as recent as August this year. I wouldn't hold my breath anyone back-porting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to work around unions:

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="dayOfWeek">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:pattern value="\d|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

For bonus points, one could even constrain the integer version thusly:

```xml
...
<xs:pattern value="[1-7]|Monday..."/>
```

Link to regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/r/WFRvH0/3).

(note: in XSD you must drop the anchors, as these are implied (as shown in my above solution). See [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) article.)

I'm thinking this might even be better than the union in my problem statement?

Comment: There is a downside to this solution. The union is made up of other base types. Other parts of the schema *could* refer to these base types, but the regular expression solution cannot. There *may* be some duplication of these base types i.o.w.